# Why isn't this a CORS request?

Tags: forms, http, cors

I am POSTing a form to another domain, and Chrome does not seem to send OPTIONS request. So, it appears to be a Simple Request.

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), only certain headers are allowed for Simple Request. The browser appears to be sending:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-CA;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,ja;q=0.5,ko;q=0.4
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 127
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: _ga=...
Host: xxx.yyy.com
Origin: http://zzz.amazonaws.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://zzz.amazonaws.com/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

Some of these headers appear to be outside of those that can be sent in a [Simple Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests). Specifically, `Cache-Control`, `Pragma` and `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests`.

It seems that these may fall under ***the headers set automatically by the user agent***.

Is there any definitive list of these headers?

Is there a way to know how they are supported by all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The limits on what headers can be set in a Simple Request refer to the headers set by the JavaScript program calling the XMLHttpRequest or fetch API.

It does not apply to headers set automatically by the browser.

(Well, with the exception of settings like `withCredentials` where the JavaScript requests a broad category of headers without setting them explicitly).